# android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

This layout in main_activity.xml does not work:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
...
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

With an error: Cannot resolve class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

There is a line in build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
```

**How do I fix it?**

---

By the way, for example:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

works fine.

Comment: Please share your android studio configuration and gradle.properties details

Comment: If in your `gradle.properties`  you have `android.useAndroidX=true` then your components will be from `androidx`  & not `android`

Comment: It's really all about `gradle.properties` and `androidx`. Thank you very much, problem solved.

Comment: Simply migrate project to AndroidX, go to (Build/Refector) > migrate to AndroidX.

Comment: I'm having troubles with one of the functions on AndroidX, so this option doesn't suitable for me.